# Meaningfulness of suggested packages

Tags: package-management

I use aptitude as my package manager. Very often packages suggest some other packages.

`xfce4` suggests `xfce4-themes` for example.

That makes sense.

But very often there are suggestions where I don't know why this is suggested. How does it help me? What are the implications?

eg. `i3` package suggests things like `libpoe-perl` or `libio-async-perl`. Okay I can inspect the information about those packages too, but very often I'm not more knowledgeable about how those libraries help `i3` in doing anything. If there is something in `i3` that relies on them, why are they only suggested and not mandatory?

Is there a standard way of getting information about the collaboration of the package I'm installing and its suggested packages?

Answer (score 2):

First about **getting information about the packages**.
You can search the package name on the site [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search) to search for the functionality of some package is you are interested. 
For your reference, the following link is for the package you have mentioned:

[libpoe_perl on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libpoe-perl/2:1.3670-1)

Similarly all packages have such details.

Second, for the **question of suggestion, recommendation**. This comes from the origins of Ubuntu i.e. Debian. The Debian FAQ ([Debian FAQ on dependencies, etc...](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-depends)) gives details as following. (probably these principles come as such in Ubuntu.)

> The Debian package system has a range of package "dependencies" which
>   are designed to indicate (in a single flag) the level at which Program
>   A can operate independently of the existence of Program B on a given
>   system:
>
> Package A **depends** on Package B if B absolutely must be installed in
>   order to run A. In some cases, A depends not only on B, but on a
>   version of B. In this case, the version dependency is usually a lower
>   limit, in the sense that A depends on any version of B more recent
>   than some specified version.
>
> Package A **recommends** Package B, if the package maintainer judges that
>   most users would not want A without also having the functionality
>   provided by B.
>
> Package A **suggests** Package B if B contains files that are related to
>   (and usually enhance) the functionality of A.
>
> Package A **conflicts** with Package B when A will not operate if B is
>   installed on the system. Most often, conflicts are cases where A
>   contains files which are an improvement over those in B. "Conflicts"
>   are often combined with "replaces".
>
> Package A **replaces** Package B when files installed by B are removed and
>   (in some cases) over-written by files in A.
>
> Package A **breaks** Package B when both packages cannot be simultaneously
>   configured in a system. The package management system will refuse to
>   install one if the other one is already installed and configured in
>   the system.
>
> Package A **provides** Package B when all of the files and functionality
>   of B are incorporated into A. This mechanism provides a way for users
>   with constrained disk space to get only that part of package A which
>   they really need.

Usually for **suggested packages**, the package developer/maintainer judges (probably based on statistics of usage and added features ) that most users would not want some package A without also having the functionality provided by some package B. In such cases suggested packages show up.